# How to dynamically hide and show tabs in tabpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

I have tabpanel and 2 items inside. I need dynamically hide or show tabs and select only one of items if hide.

Code example

```
{
     xtype    : 'tabpanel',
     items: [
           {
                xtype: 'container',
                title : 'Group Info'
           },
           {
                xtype: 'container',
                title : 'Product Info'
           },
         ]
    }
```

So in some cases I have to hide tabs and show only product info container...

Comment: What version of Ext? Can you post your code?Did you search for similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494264/how-do-i-programmatically-hide-tab-in-the-tabpanel-extjs-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so the answer is

```
var tabPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myTabPanel');
tabPanel = tabPanel[0];
tabPanel.getTabBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just get a reference to the tab and use method hide http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-hide

```
//function in a controller

hideTab : function(){
    var tab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tab[title='Group Info]')[0];
    tab.hide()
}
```